# Link send Email to Outlook and Subject is equal to cell value vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, vba, macros

I've created an hyperlink name **send** I want it, when the user click it
outlook will automatically display. and I want subject will equivalent to cell value

example here's my col:

```
col 1     |col 2    |col3   |col 4    |col5    | col 6   |col 7
2019-001  |  ...    | ...   | ...     | ...    |Reports  |send
2019-002  |  ...    | ...   | ...     | ...    |Receipt  |send
...
```

the col 7 is the hyperlink, and when it clicked the outlook will display.
on the subject pane of the email I want to display **col 1 & col 6**
example: **2019-001 - Reports**

subject will depends on the value where they clicked the **send** link.

but I don't know how to apply it on my code.

I just simply create this

```
Range("G5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "send"
Range("G5").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
"email add", TextToDisplay:="send"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G5:G1222"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

and now I don't know how to add what I want for the subject.
need help thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The macro you are writing puts a static Mailto link into the cell.
You could also build a dynamic Mailto link directly in the cell without the VBA.

To get started, here are the "mailto:" attributes:
From Yoast.com [Guide: MailTo Links](https://developer.yoast.com/guide-mailto-links/)

- mailto:  to set the recipient, or recipients, separate with comma
- Followed by a "**?**" if there are attributes. Preceed subsequent attributes with "**&**"
- **cc=** to set the CC recipient(s) **bcc=** to set the BCC recipient(s)
- **subject=** to set the email subject, URL encode for longer sentences,
  so replace spaces with %20, etc.
- **body=** to set the body of the message, you can add entire sentences here,
  including line breaks. Line breaks should be converted to %0D%0A.

Example String: "mailto:info@example.com?subject=subject&cc=cc@example.com"
So the code you are writing would look like:

`ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="mailto:info@example.com?subject=subject&cc=cc@example.com"`

To programmatically form the string use

`... Address:="mailto:" & Range("A1") & "?subject=" & Range("A2") ...`
where A1 is the cell with the email address and so forth.

This is a static solution because the macro will need to be run again to update the "send" link if the information in these cells are changed.

Dynamic solution without vba:

Use this formula in the "send" cell:

`=HYPERLINK("mailto:" & A1 & "?subject=" & A2  & "&body=" & A3,"send")`

There may be a detail or two to work out with the body value if there are non standard line breaks in the cell.

Use of a proper name and email address generally works as well:

- Cell A1=`first recipient<info@example.com>`
- `... Address:="mailto:first recipient<info@example.com>?subject=subject ..."`

Comment: For the OP, the email subject will be a concatenation of the two fields including a hyphen: `=HYPERLINK("mailto:" & A1 & "?subject=" & Col1 & " - " & Col6 ,"send")` where Col1 and Col6 are cell references in the OP sample.

Comment: wow thanks! it worked perfectly!! :) one question: is it possible when using **mailto:** instead of the default mail recommended by windows 10, Outlook should be the one will pop out? or I just need to change thru the settings for the default mail app?

Comment: For myself in testing, my gmail opened. Probably the OS default mail client. Also, other mechanisms to send mail do exist. One such is a VBA solution using CreateObject("Outlook.Application")  and with it Attachments.Add (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302602/sending-email-attachments-from-excel-via-vba)